# Why can this code read from stdin when it should be empty?

Tags: c, macos, io, terminal

The code comes from the Kilo project:

```c
/*
 * Use write() and terminal escape (ESC) sequence
 * to query cursor position.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ESC 27

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char buf[32];
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int rows, cols;

    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\033[6n", 4);

    while (i < sizeof(buf)-1) {
        if (read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+i,1) != 1) break;
        if (buf[i] == 'R') break;
        i++;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';

    /* Parse it. */
    if (buf[0] != ESC || buf[1] != '[') return -1;
    if (sscanf(buf+2,"%d;%d",&rows,&cols) != 2) return -1;
    printf("%d %d\n", rows, cols);

    return 0;
}
```

The result in OS X terminal.app is:

```
➜  /Users/name/Desktop/demo ./write
^[[44;1R
44 1
➜  /Users/name/Desktop/demo 
➜  /Users/name/Desktop/demo
```

The result has 5 lines, but I can't understand the actions:

1. Why does it output those characters in line 2? Because the `write()` function has written some characters to `STDOUT`? If yes, how can I suppress this output?
2. Why can the `read()` function read something from `STDIN`? I just think `STDIN` should be empty now because I have not pressed any key.
3. After line 2, it will block. Why must I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?
4. Why is line 4 empty? Because of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> that I just pressed?

Running in OS X 10.11.6 Terminal.app

Comment: `^[[` is a terminal control sequence. e.g. "move cursor to position x,y", or "change text color to red".

Comment: yes, I know the function of control sequence. But why it can read from STDIN?

Comment: The `read` function will *block* until there is something to read. Once you press the enter key, the line is sent to your program so it can read it.

Comment: @user3121023 So your meaning is the result of escape code will show in STDIN then read() can read cursor position from STDIN? if yes, how to suppress the line 2 output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape sequence `\e[6n` is used to query the terminal for the cursor position.  The terminal answers by feeding characters as if they had been typed by the user.  The answer format is `\e[y;xR` where `y` is the row number and `x` the column number, both `1` based. Here `\e[44;1R` which is echoed by the terminal in line mode, like any other user input. Note that the escape byte is echoed as `^[`.  You can edit this output with the backspace key.  Try modifying the column number by changing it to `^[[44;11R` and see the effect when you press ENTER.

The program tries to read this input but since the terminal is in line mode, you need to type the ENTER key for a full line of input to become available to the system.

Note that the program reads this input from the system byte by byte with individual `read()` system calls. It stops reading when it gets an `R`, therefore the linefeed stays in the system buffers.

The program's `sscanf()` parses the `\e[44;1`, prints `44 1` (row 44, column 1) and exits.

The shell echoes a command prompt, reads the pending linefeed and echoes another command prompt.

I'm not sure how to suppress the line2 output. I doubt redirecting stdout would make a difference.

Setting the terminal in raw mode with the `stty()` system call before the `write()` should prevent this output as well as the need for the ENTER key.  If you change the terminal mode, aka the *line discipline*, remember to save the current settings and restore them before exiting the program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how to suppress the line2 output? Redirect STDOUT?

Comment: @merito: I updated the answer with a potential solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to not need the return, you need to take the terminal out of canonical mode.  If you want it to not echo the response string, you need to disable echoing.  You do both of those with `tcsetattr`.  Add to your program:

At the top:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
```

At the start of `main`:

```
struct termios old, modified;

if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old) < 0) {
    if (errno == ENOTTY)
        fprintf(stderr, "input is not a terminal -- can't query position\n");
    else
        perror("tcgetattr");
    exit(1); }
modified = old;
modified.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &modified);
```

At the end of `main` (before the return):

```
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old);
```

This disables canonical mode and echoing at the start of the program, and restores the previous settings afterwards.

Also, you actually want to write the query sequence to `STDIN_FILENO` rather than `STDOUT_FILENO`.  That way it will continue to work properly even if you redirect the output somewhere...